# Ways other than て-form and たり～たり～ to connect several sentences and ideas together

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if someone can give me some examples because I don't remember quite well from my Japanese classes (because we rarely used this following way), how to connect more sentences? Until now I have mostly used the て form and たり～たりする form, but I remember that there was another way, and I want to know if I'm right, **by using the stems of the verbs**. I vaguely remember a sentence from one of my textbooks and that's why I wanted a reminder of some sort.

I'm sorry if I didn't explain it quite well, because I don't remember the rule on how to construct sentences like that. Most of the time, me and my classmates resorted to the て form and made very very short phrases back then.

Answer (score 0):

In written Japanese (only) you can connect sentences using the "-masu stem".  This is very common in newspapers.

This is from [NHK news](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180718/k10011538811000.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-main_004):

> ヨーロッパ委員会は３年前から調査を進めてきましたが、グーグルの手法が、日本の独占禁止法に当たるＥＵ競争法に違反すると最終的に**判断し**、43億ユーロ余り、日本円にしておよそ5700億円の制裁金を科すと発表しました

The above bolded verb is just the stem (of a する verb).  It has the same meaning as the て-form.

Comment: その例文、「判断**して** 、」とは言い換えられますけど、「43億ユーロ余**って** 」とは言い換えられませんよね。この「43億ユーロ余り」は "a little more than €4.3 billion", "over €4.3 billion" (≂「43億ユーロ以上」) って意味で、「日本円にしておよそ5700億円」と同格なんで。。

Comment: @Chocolate ok edited to reflect

Comment: `In written Japanese (only)...`  I think "only" is a bit presumptuous.  Maybe "mostly" or "often", but not "only".